# firebase (v9) How to get 'isNewUser' info after Google redirect?

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I would like to check if the user is new after a Google redirect. Inside the `signInWithEmailLink` routine this works

```
let credential = await signInWithEmailLink(auth, email, window.location.href)
const details = getAdditionalUserInfo(credential)
const isNewUser = details.isNewUser
```

but logging this credential gives `UserCredentialImpl` and the credential after the redirect `OAuthCredential`
So this doesn't work

```
 const redirectResult = await getRedirectResult(auth)
        if(redirectResult) {
            try {
                const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(redirectResult);
                console.log('credential', credential)
                const details = getAdditionalUserInfo(credential)
                const isNewUser = details.isNewUser           
            } catch (error) {
                const email = error.email;
                const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
                console.log('error while signing in with google - getting redirect result', email, credential, error)
            }
        }
```

with the IDE already complaining *"Argument type OAuthCredential is not assignable to parameter type UserCredential"* and the error *"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isAnonymous')"*

How can the `.isNewUser` info be read after the redirect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just realized that the redirectResult is of type `UserCredentialImpl` so this works

```
const redirectResult = await getRedirectResult(auth)
        if(redirectResult) {
            try {      
                const details = getAdditionalUserInfo(redirectResult)
                const isNewUser = details.isNewUser
                ...           
            } catch (error) {
                ...
            }
        }
```